# How to align a text to center horizontally and also to the bottom of page?

Tags: css

I want to align a text to center of the page horizontally and also at the bottom of the page, with a background to text. The text here is variable. I want to break the text into more lines, if it crosses `width` more than 30% of screen size.

I am either able to align div to center or stick to bottom of the page, but couldn't do both. When I give `position` to `absolute` or `fixed`, The center alignment is missing and I have to give `left: 30%` to move it right.

This is the HTML

```
<div class="div-1">
  <div class="div-2">
    Hey this is an amazing way to do this
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.div-1 {
  height: 100vh;
}
.div-2 {
  bottom: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  max-width: 30%;
}
```

Can someone suggest the perfect way to do this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, change `className` to `class`. Then add

```
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
bottom: 20px;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
margin: 0 auto;
```

to `.div-2`

```css
.div-1 {
    height: 100vh;
  }
  .div-2 {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    max-width: 30%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 20px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="div-1">
      <div class="div-2">
        Hey this is an amazing way to do this
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: My code is in "React" so we need to use "ClassName"

Comment: Alright, Next time maybe add a React tag to the question.

Comment: no need to add *react* tag to the question if the issue is only related to CSS but we can post a valid react code

Comment: Yeah. I updated it to "class". As I got a negative score for dis

Answer (score 0):

You should use the least amount of tag as possible.
In order to center horizontal, use text-align: center and make sure that the width of the container is 100%.
To reduce the width of the text; use padding for the container.

```
<footer>
  Hey this is an amazing way to do this
</footer>

footer {
  position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  text-align: center; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 35%; background: blue; color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this. You can use className as you are using it in React.

```css
.div-1 {
    height: 100vh;
}
.div-2 {
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    max-width: 30%;
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-1">
  <div class="div-2">
    Hey this is an amazing way to do this
  </div>
</div>
```